# GWT - How to deliver medical image from server to client where users can do some pixel level processing on image

Tags: gwt, image-processing

I am working on a GWT based web app for medical image display and processing. The problem is this kind of medical image do not have the standarded fomat and it is a huge bytearray (size: over 18M). I have to directly read the image byte array and send it to the client for display and further processing. When I transfer a little part of the image (less than 32kb), the client display the pixels normally. But when I transfer the whole image, the console promotes error:

> [enter code hereERROR]javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: **Java heap space**
>
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.append(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:583)
>   ...

This might be the size limitation of data transfer within GWT, as I've found other‘s solution like:

**encode the byte array by using com.google.gwt.user.server.Base64Utils.toBase64(byte[]) . But this method does not work for IE 7. and IE8 has 32kb limit.. IE9 does not have this limit.**

> **Client side:**
>
> -ImageService.java
>
> -ImageServiceAsync.java
>
> -WebImage.java (interface)
>
> -ImageArray.java (store the image data from server)
>
> **Server side:**
>
> -ImageServiceImpl.java

I used a button to active this image data delivery. In the background, ImageServiceImpl read a medical image from disk file and send the data array to client. Now as the limitation that I metioned above, this process will not be succesful if I sent the whole image data. How can I do to complete this process succesfully? I wonder if there is a way to continuously deliver many small parts (<32kb) of data array from server to client when I just click the button once. So I can divide the image into many small parts to perform that. Or there are some other mechanisms useful for this task that I donot know.

Comment: I used GWT with HTML5 element to perform the image processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at a Map Tiler similar to the way Google maps breaks up images and displays them.  Here is a starting place http://www.maptiler.org/ .  Here is an example of a company that has done exactly what you are trying to do https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Google+Maps+Image+Viewer+Module

Comment: It is an amazing application, thanks for your introduction. But I wonder if there is a way to solve my problem within GWT. If not, i will consider other tools.

Comment: You wouldn't find anything to slice up your image into tiles inside gwt - that is a server side operation and gwt only runs on the client.  But the google map style display you can probably find with a gwt widget.  If not you can easily put a wrapper around the js to make your own widget.

Comment: What about divide into many parts of image on the server-side and deliver them to the client? The server side is pure java. I am not sure the probability of doing that.

Comment: The google map style is nice for that as I saw your introduction. At present stage, I use GWTCanvas to display the image with HTML5 element. This can provide many image processing in pixel level. How can I combine the google map style with gwt? I am a freshman on gwt and looking forward for your experience. Thanks a million.